# How do I determine the spark plug gap for a 1999 Mercedes E320 4matic Sedan?

Tags: sparkplugs, mercedes-benz, e320

I've been looking all over trying to see if there is any information but I haven't found it. I'm about to replace the spark plugs, but I need to know the correct gap. I purchased NGK 4696 Iridium spark plugs. I'm not sure if the same gap will give the same amount of power.

Comment: If you bought plugs for your particular car, they should be pre-gapped correctly.  Measure them to make sure, but they should be correct at I believe .040 or .039 (1mm).  Do you think they are wrong or not for your car?

Comment: Did you check on or around the core support area in the engine bay? I don't know about overseas, but here in the States most vehicles have an emissions sticker which tells what the plug gap should be.

Comment: Be careful, Iridium spark plugs are really easy to damage when gaping. The center electrode is very fragile.